# Sim Controller is hidden in Flash CC on mac and I can't get it back

Tags: ios, macos, flash, air, multi-touch

The SimController on my Flash to iOs app has stopped showing up. It launches and if I 4-finger swipe up on the trackpad I can see the window, but clicking on it or dragging it around just simply doesn't bring it back into view. I've also tried right clicking and showing all windows (again, I can see it as a small window) but it won't come back.

I've restarted the mac and Flash many times.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this appears to be linked to the fact that I have an external monitor connected to my Mac. After I removed the external monitor and restarted Flash and the Mac once or twice, the Simulator re-appeared out of its own accord.